# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: programs

Tags: laravel-5.7

I have searched multiple questions similar to my question but it still doesn't solve it.

Here is my web.php (route)

```
Route::get('/page/dpage1','ApplyProgramController@index')->name('dpage1');
Route::get('/page/dpage1', 'ApplyProgramController@create');
Route::post('/page/dpage1','ApplyProgramController@store');
```

My blade.php

```
 <tr>
               <strong>
                <th>Kod Program</th>
                <th>Nama Program</th>
                <th>Jawatan</th>
                <th>Mohon</th>
              </strong>
            </tr>


          @foreach($programs as $program)
   <tr>

           <td><strong> Kod Program : {{ $program->kod_program}}</strong></td>
<td>
  <input type="text" name="kod_program" readonly value="{{ $program->kod_program}}" class="form-control"></td>




           <td><strong> Nama Program :</strong></td>
<td>
  <input type="text" name="nama_program" readonly value="{{ $program->nama_program}}" class="form-control"></td>

</tr>
    <td>
```

The error is at the row `@foreach($programs as $program)`.

Here is my controller php

```
class ApplyProgramController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
         $programs = Program::all();
         dd($programs);
         return view('page.dropdown1',compact('programs');
```

I tried several methods such as changing compact to `['programs'=>$program]`. When I tried using `ifisset($programs)`, I am able to view the blade page but there is no data shown on the page from my database. The code earlier can be used from the other pages.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: alright sorry for that

Comment: Try: `return view('page.dropdown1')->with($programs, 'programs');` instead of `return view('page.dropdown1',compact('programs');`

Comment: i tried but still the same error

Comment: did you manage to solve this?